# Calculate routes in an array

Tags: java

everyone,
Need your help, I got a task to write a method in java.
What this method does is check whether there is a path from the beginning of the array that enables reaching the end of the array by the values in the array.
For example:
If I received the array:
2 4 1 6 4 2 4 3 5
The answer returned will be true because there is a path that begins with cell 0, two cells go to the right
To cell 2, from there one compartment left to cell 1, and from there four cells to the right cell 5, then again two
Cells right to cell 7, from there three cells left to cell 4 and from there four cells to the right cell
8 which is the last in the array.

I managed to build a good algorithm, but I can not figure out what is wrong with my code.
Would appreciate help .

this is my code:

```
    public static boolean isWay(int []a){
if(a[0]==0)//not go to anywhere
    return false;
    return isWay(a,0);
}
private static boolean isWay (int[]a,int i){
    if(i==a.length)
        return true;
    if(a[i]==0)
        return false;
    int temp = new int [i];
    a[i]=0;
    if(i+temp<a.length&& i-temp>0)
        return (isWay(a,i+temp))||isWay(a,i-temp);
    if(i+temp<a.length)
        return (isWay(a,i+temp));
    if(i-temp>0)
        return (isWay(a,i-temp));
    return false;
```

Comment: there is no code supplied in your question

Comment: Hi , Look on the image

Comment: Copy and paste your code.

Comment: ok look now....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

- `int temp = new int [i];` should probably be `int temp = a[i];`
- you check whether `i + temp < a.length`, but this way you can *never* find a `temp` such that `i + temp == a.length`; change `<` to `<=`

Also, you could simplify your code by moving the index-out-of-bounds-check:

```
private static boolean isWay(int[] a, int i) {
    if (i == a.length)
        return true;
    if (i < 0 || i > a.length) // just check here
        return false;
    if (a[i] == 0)
        return false;
    int temp = a[i];
    a[i] = 0;
    return (isWay(a, i + temp)) || isWay(a, i - temp);
}
```

Comment: i got ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with this code when i try this array : 1,4,3,1,2,4,3 i need to get false .

Comment: @EdenTamam Fixed. The index should of course be checked _before_ testing whether the value at that index is `0`...